# When updating a mesh, does 'glBufferSubdata' belong in the update or render function?

Tags: rendering, game-loop

When updating a mesh, does the `glBufferSubdata` call belong in the update function, or the render function?

I'm trying to organize my game appropriately. and knowing this would help me.  This is my first game, and I want to structure it properly.

Comment: That depends entirely on what, in general, your "update" function does and what your "render" function does.

Comment: Yes, this is just a cosmetic decision.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what the purpose of the `update` and `render` functions you wrote and are referring to are.

The purpose of [`glBufferSubData`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml) is to update, in whole or in part, the data stored in an OpenGL buffer object. It is *fundamentally* a rendering operation, and so it absolutely belongs in render code.

Consequently if you are asking if the function belongs in the "update-the-game-logic" function called `update` or the "render the mesh" function called `render`, the answer is the latter. In this case you're talking about the separation of game state and specific gameplay logic from the act of rendering, which is generally a good separation, and should be enforced (if that is what your `update` is doing, it shouldn't be part of the `mesh` class at all because that is breaking that separation).

However if your `update` function *is* a render-specific update (for example, one that applies animation data to a mesh in some form, or one that pushes through new values for time-based shader parameters), then it is probably a reasonable approach to have your `glBufferSubData` call in *that* function rather than `render`, because fundamentally the call is about updating render information. This approach also makes it a little more obvious that you could update a mesh once to make it current, and then render it multiple times and helps keep that behavior separation in place, reducing the length of the `render` method which might otherwise need to have some lazy-evaluation checks so you didn't needlessly call `glBufferSubData` more times than you wanted to.